# Foreign keys to prevent "orphan" file rows in a database for a scenario involving projects, files and downloads

Tags: postgresql, database-design, foreign-key

In a system that monitors a file mirror by regularly downloading a file, I want to store a history of the results. So I have three tables:

```
┌──────────┐ ┌──────────────────┐ ┌────────┐
│projects  │ │downloads         │ │files   │
├──────────┤ ├──────────────────┤ ├────────┤
│project_id│ │download_id       │ │file_id │
│name      │ │project_id        │ │contents│
│(FK?)     │ │download_timestamp│ │(FK?)   │
└──────────┘ │file_id           │ └────────┘
             │(FK?)             │
             └──────────────────┘
```

- All `downloads` and `files` belong to a `project`.
- Everytime a `file` is downloaded, a new `download` is inserted.
- If the same contents already exists in the `files` table for the same `project`, the new `download` will point to the existing `file`, otherwise a new `file` is also inserted.

I have two foreign keys in `downloads`, `project_id` and `file_id`. Is there a better structure, especially one that prevents orphaned `files` (`files` without an associated `download`)?

Answer (score -1):

Schematically (out of syntax).

Structures:

```
CREATE TABLE project ( project_id identity,
                       primary key (project_id),
                       name varchar,
                       unique (name) );

CREATE TABLE file ( file_id identity,
                    primary key (file_id),
                    filelink varchar,
                    content varchar,
                    unique (bf(file_link || content)) );

CREATE TABLE download ( download_id identity,
                        primary key (download_id),
                        project_id,
                        foreign key (project_id) references project (project_id),
                        file_id,
                        foreign key (file_id) references file (file_id),
                        download_timestamp default current_timestamp );
```

Insertion:

```
INSERT INTO project (name)
VALUES (@name)
ON CONFLICT (name) DO NOTHING;

INSERT INTO file (filelink, content)
VALUES (@filelink, @content)
ON CONFLICT (filelink, content) DO NOTHING;

INSERT INTO downloads (project_id, file_id)
SELECT project.project_id, file.file_id
FROM project, file
WHERE project.name = @name
  AND file.filelink = @filelink
  AND file.content = @content;
```

Comment: How is this different from my structure? It still allows `files` without an associated `download`.

Comment: @AndreKR 1) It is NOT a problem at all... 2) You cannot provide both direct and backward reference integrity (forbid both file without download and download without file), because if you try to do it, you can't insert data - any insert will fail because no referenced record. To solve it you'll need one more table. 3) And one more reason - if you'll delete some project and its downloads, the files remains on HDD, and it makes no sense to delete information about them. Let's will unbound...

Comment: There are no files on HDD, everything is in the database. I edited the question to make that more clear. By "orphaned file" I mean a `files` entry that no `downloads` entry points to. And of course I would make all the foreign keys deferrable.

Comment: @AndreKR *By "orphaned file" I mean a files entry that no downloads entry points to.* To avoid these files to appear while delete referenced download set ON DELETE CASCADE action for FK. To avoid these files to appear while update forbid this action - the scheme do not provide updates. You cannot avoid these files to appear while insert - they  are produced in the above procedure between 2nd and 3rd query, so they are legitimate. You must 1) check the whole procedure is performed without errors (wrap it into transaction) 2) prevent insertion performed not by this procedure.

Comment: *"To avoid these files to appear while delete referenced download set ON DELETE CASCADE action for FK."* What? In your proposal `downloads` references `files`. Deleting downloads should do nothing about `files`, even with `ON DELETE CASCADE`.

Comment: @AndreKR Oh, yes, it is for backward (file) delete. For download delete the only solution seems to be a trigger which checks that there is no reference to this file from another downloads, and delete file if deleted download is the only which references to this file. And the best way is forbid any altering queries to this scheme, performing all data manipulations via stored procedures only.